# When I set $.mask.definitions['#'] it is overriding other input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have html code I want to give format my phone are , and I am using this code on document.ready() , I want to fix first 2 characters but mask.definitions affects other inputs I just want to use this options for Phone input

I want to format like this  0 (5__) ___ __ __ , but 0 (5__) this part should be not editable.

```
<input type="text" name="Data.Phone" id="Phone" readonly required>
   <script>
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            $.mask.definitions['#'] = $.mask.definitions['9'];  //Set # to do what 9 does
                            $.mask.definitions['9'] = null;//Remove 9 as a masking character
                            $("#Phone").mask("0(5##) ### ## ##");
                        });
                      
                    </script>
```

Comment: I am using this library <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>